# Saving matrix class to Application Settings VB.net

Tags: vb.net, matrix, application-settings

In VB.net I have a matrix object which I'm trying to save away in application settings and Im not recovering the settings correctly.

```
Private mMatrixHR As New Matrix
...
My.Settings.MatrixHR = mMatrixHR
...
My.Settings.Save()
```

When I look at the user.config file I see:

```
        <setting name="MatrixHR" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value>
                <Matrix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
            </value>
        </setting>
```

Obviously no matrix data has been saved to file.

Can anyone explain what Im doing wrong ?

Thanks

J

Comment: Your Matrix class must be Xml Serializable. Can you post the contents of the class?

Comment: What values from the matrix are you trying to save?

Comment: Just the matrix elements really. I see now the way to do this is to create a class that contains the translation, scale and rotation parameters that are used to generate the matrix and serialize that instead.

Answer (score 0):

its the dot.net matrix class

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix
```

Since I can choose this type in the application settings configuration, I had assumed it would be serializable.

J

Comment: Add this as a comment to your question.  Not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Drawing.Drawing2d.Matrix class is not serializable.  Calling

```
mMatrixHR.GetType().IsSerializable()
```

will return False.

Answer (score 0):

A class must be serializable to XML to be saved in App Settings. To be XML-serializable, a class must have Read/Write properties (only those properties are going to get persisted to XML). Since the Matrix class only has ReadOnly properties, nothing is serialized.

You'll have to create your own class which exposes the data you want to serialize with read/write properties.